Limited data returned from GA4 add on to Google sheet
When I am using the GA4 report builder add on in google sheet, the data returned is limited to 10000 rows, how can I return the whole data?
I tried to return the whole data for the selected period of time, I got it limited to 10000 row only.

You can use GA4 Magic Reports, it is free as the official add-on and has all the features working. It allows you to extend the limit beyond 10000 with field "Offset" in the add-on.
You just need to follow these steps. Let's take an example, the one shown in the screenshot below:
Imagine you have a report that should return 12,428 rows, but because of Google's limitation you see only the first 10,000.
With the offset field is possible to split the report into two pages.
1️⃣ Report 1: Offset blank (or 0) and Limit 10,000
2️⃣ Report 2: Offset 10,000 and Limit 10,000
In this way, the first request returns the first 10,000 rows. The second request sets the offset to the limit of the first request (10,000), so in the second report you can find the other 2,428 rows.
Very simple :)
To avoid it being seen as spam I am not including the link to the add-on, you just search for GA4 Magic Reports in the Google Workspace Marketplace as you already did with the GA4 report builder add on.
